# Is there a standard library like Quick Look framework for icons in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, icons, thumbnails

I need to list the contents of a folder in the app's documents' folder and wonder if there exists a component in the iOS frameworks that returns an UIImage or something for a particular file.

So, as the title says; Is there a standard framework that can be used or would I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, create an instance of `UIDocumentInteractionController`, and query its `icons` property:

```
- (UIImage *)iconForFile: (NSURL *)fileURL {
    UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    if (controller) {
        return [controller.icons lastObject]; // arbitrary selection--gives you the largest icon in this case
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I don't know of a way to get the icon without using `UIDocumentInteractionController` off the top of my head.

Note that this gives you the document icon for the file, but *not* a preview of it. There's no inbuilt preview mechanism in iOS.